# Using global nodes to control environment quality?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm working on a fairly large environment render with multiple houses, trees, grass etc. and I'm on the limit of maxing out my GPU memory. Depending on what angle I'm doing a render, I will manually hide objects outside the viewport or lower subdivions, disable displacements or make glass non reflective to avoid maxing out my GPU memory limit. It works but it's really time time consuming and I do forget to redo those changes when I switch to the next angle.

I'm curious is there a good workflow using nodes to control quality? For example if I could have a set of nodes with values from 0-5, I could somehow utilize those values on textures or controlling will some objects be visible?

I could not find any tutorial relating to this kind of workflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Simplify panel to do some of this with global control.

[image]