# my Project is too heavy that it stops the computer

Tags: modeling, faces

[image]

So this is the picture of my small project
and bc it has so many faces that the file itself is over 5.2 GB

My computer stops sometimes for about 10 minutes.
and this is really frustrating.

Is this understandable in most cases?
like, does most blender project normally goes over 5GB?

if there's any way to prevent the computer stopping
or decreasing the project's capacity tremendously, please let me know

Comment: Well, 5 GB is too large compared to normal file sizes....you might be having a lot of vertices, or too much baked animations and rigidbodies....still I think 5 GB is tremendous comparing it to your given screenshot

Comment: Try enabling *Compress File* from Edit > Preferences > Save & Load > Compress File and save the file again, and see if the file size gets reduced

Comment: Does this help you? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/218229/110840

Comment: I'll try using simplify as suggested

Comment: to be honest, in most cases you don't need so much faces/vertices as you have. Even without loosing any quality in rendering. So you should also think about retopologize your model or unsubdividing/remeshing. Lot's of beginner (and i made that too) make the mistake to make more subdivisions than necessary just to be sure it looks good. Often even just a "shade smooth" is enough.

Comment: How many vertices has your scene? You can check it in the statistic overlay or in the status bar (right-click it if the statistics are not displayed). Have you used a *Subdivision Surface* modifier or a *Multires* modifier? The *Simplify* feature only helps you if you haven't applied the modifiers. To give you some numbers: Blender's [Rain character](https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da) is in a 25 MB file + 193 MB textures. The file of my human-sized model with a *Multires* modifier (600k vertices) is about 52 MB. If yours is 100x bigger there is something wrong.