# Good looking moderate poly trees for 3.0 cycles; Mtree

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I am working on a landscape scene and want some moderate poly spruce trees that look good in cycles.

I used MTree 4.0.2 to generate a tree and applied heavy leaf distribution of very small size, which is a geometry node setup.  I decimated my tree to reduce the poly count but the object remains very heavy due to the leaf size/distribution.  If I 'apply' the geometry node modifier my leaves disappear.

I see all these various landscape tutorials where people scatter a lot of good looking plant assets around, but often 'purchased' assets.  I am trying to build my own assets and/or use free ones - I would love advice on how to create moderately sized assets or where to find decent ones.

So the basic questions are:

How can I reduce my Mtree/geometry node tree to a more reasonable size?
What are good ways to produce nice looking trees that are not too big?

As you can see from the screenshot, 350,000 vertices means I can't add too many trees to my landscape.  I've tried decimating, but I think the leaf count is just too high.  Ideally I'd like to put about 10-30 trees into my scene and not blocky super low poly versions.

[image]

Comment: The definition of low poly can be subjective. The lowest you can go is a quad with a png texture of a tree set with alpha transparency. Doesn't work for close-ups though

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244520/scene-is-too-heavy-how-to-identify-most-expensive-objects/244531#244531   This helped me a lot, not just with MTrees but other objects too.  I find it to be a handy project inspector