# Blender 3.0.1 How to import 'tabulate' into script

Tags: python

thx for the patience.  I'm not very familiar with python and I am trying to use a tabulate import but get errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\CheckObejctSize.py", line 5, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

I've read a whole bunch of threads on what to do, but none have helped.  I was going to use the blender/pip to add tabulate but I can't seem to even find pip.

I found a thread that suggested:

```
import ensurepip
ensurepip.bootstrap()
pybin = bpy.app.binary_path_python
subprocess.check_call([pybin, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'tabulate'])
```

which produced
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in links: c:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp99hzlnij
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\site-packages (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files\blender foundation\blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\site-packages (21.2.3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\CheckObejctSize.py", line 10, in 
AttributeError: 'bpy.app' object has no attribute 'binary_path_python'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Why can't I find pip when it seems that it's already there and how can I get tabulate import working in Blender 3.0 scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convoluted but I got it to work:

- Download the get-pip.py file from the web.  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
- Place it in ...Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin
- Run Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python> .\bin\python.exe ./bin/get-pip.py

You will see:

```
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 8.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, pip
  WARNING: The script wheel.exe is installed in 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-21.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.2.3
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.9.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-22.0.3 wheel-0.37.1
```

- This will have created a Scripts directory, now I can use pip3 to install
- Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python> ./Scripts/pip3 install tabulate

With Subsequent Blender upgrades I ran into problems again, and now I have this script which has been working

```
# From https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/installing-python-packages-with-pip-in-blender-on-windows-10/
import subprocess
import sys
import os
 
python_exe = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'bin', 'python.exe')
target = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'lib', 'site-packages')
print('target is: ' + target)

print('sys.path is: ')
for i in sys.path:
    print(i, end="")
# print('sys.path is: ' + sys.path)
print('HELLO')
print('sys.executable is: ' + sys.executable)
 
 
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'ensurepip'])
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip'])

subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'uninstall', 'pip', 'setuptools'])
 
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'numpy', '-t', target])
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'tabulate', '-t', target])
subprocess.call([python_exe, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'scipy', '-t', target])
 
print('FINISHED')
```

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244520/scene-is-too-heavy-how-to-identify-most-expensive-objects/244531#244531 to understand how this is used.