# How to make program run faster for one file?

Tags: modeling, particles

One of my blender files runs extremely slow, I'm guessing this is because it just contains too much content/complexity and the more I add the slower it gets. It's to the point that editing undo/redo will take like 20-30 seconds every time I press it. Is there any suggestions to how I can increase the speed on this? I should also mention that my scene contains grass.

Other questions talk about speeding up the whole program, not just for one project

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218229/using-global-nodes-to-control-environment-quality/218245#218245 - and toggling your particle systems' viewport visibility (eyeball icon)

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting some objects, putting them in a folder in the outliner, and clicking on the little checkbox you see. This tends to speed things up quickly[image]

Try to do this with all assets you aren't working with right away.

Other ways to speed up Blender include (but aren't limited to):

• Using proxies

• Using lower texture resolutions

• Not always working in render preview mode

• Enabling 'frame dropping' for animations

• etc.

Honestly, there are a load of great youtube videos and articles out there for this!

Comment: Thank you! I should've mentioned that even with hiding the objects in viewpoint shading is very slow as well. But I will try lowering texture resolutions and etc,

Comment: See the edited answer. It's a checkbox, not an eye icon. Try that!